# 'npm update' command is not working to update dependencies in Angular2

Tags: angular, npm

I want to update my outdated dependencies in Angular 2. when I run `npm outdated`, it displayed some outdated dependencies but when I try to update them with `npm update` command is not working for me. My npm version is `5.3.0`.

```
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^4.3.4",
"@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
"@angular/common": "^4.3.4",
"@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^4.3.4",
"@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
"@ngui/tab": "^0.5.0",
"angular-route": "^1.6.5",
"angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
"angular2-social-login": "^3.1.1",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
"bootstrap-sidebar": "^0.2.2-retry",
"chart.js": "^2.6.0",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
"ng2-toastr": "^4.1.2",
"ng2-validators": "^2.2.0",
"rxjs": "^5.1.0",
"zone.js": "^0.8.4"
 },
"devDependencies": {
"@angular/cli": "1.3.1",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
"@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
"@types/node": "~8.0.24",
"codelyzer": "~3.1.2",
"jasmine-core": "~2.7.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma": "~1.7.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
"karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"protractor": "~5.1.2",
"ts-node": "~3.3.0",
"tslint": "~5.6.0",
"typescript": "~2.4.2"
}
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your package.json? also, does it produce any stacktrace? please post it too

Comment: npm update compares the existing versions in node_modules with the versions in package.json, you need to manually update versions in package.json

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: You can try installing npm-check package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check and simply run `npm-check -u` inside your project. It will show you interactive menu and you'll be able to check which packages you want to update.

Comment: I ran npm install -g npm-check-updates, after that i ran npm-check-updates -u. After that terminal said to run npm update, but i don't know why  it is not working..and it is saying proxy or have a bad network connection.

Comment: You missread what I answered, I wanted you to install `npm-check`, not `npm-check-updates`. Try again using npm-check :)

Comment: Thank you, dependencies got updated.

Comment: @BhavaniRaju let me add an answer, so we can mark this question as solved.

Comment: when i ran ncu -u command it updated all dependencies. Once it done i deleted node_modules and re-installed them. Now it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this package ...

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates
```

and then run

```
ncu -u
```

then:

DELETE your node_modules folder and reinstall dependencies with `npm install`
But i suggest to you to be `carefully` ..cause many times not all dependencies settled to latest version are fine ...

Usually i use `VSCODE` which have a nice features ... you can put the cursor on the package in package.json and it gives to you the latest version of the package .. so you can choose `manually`

Hope it helps you

Comment: i tried  above command to update dependencies but it did not work for me.

Comment: It is not showing any error, but saying that run 'npm update' or 'ncu -a'. I tried with both commands but dependencies are not updating. And it saying you have a problem with network connectivity. Is there any modifications to change my network settings for update dependencies?

Comment: mmm no it looks like you have no line or something similar  .. you have to run ncu -u and then save your package.json .. and then delete yur node_modules and run again npm install

Comment: Any way all required dependencies got updated, but when i try to run 'npm outdated' command it is still showing those updated dependencies as outdated. :)

Comment: have you DELETE the NODE_MODULES ..and reinstall with npm install AFTER have updated them with ncu -u??

Comment: Thank you all who responded to my question.

Comment: No, do i  need to delete node_modules and again install node_modules?

Comment: YEESSSS ... cause if you don't do it ... the modules in the node folder are the OLD ... so delete and re install after the ncu -u

Comment: Thanks a lot, i deleted node_modules and re-installed. it's working perfectly now.  And also it is not showing any outdated dependencies.

Comment: great ..so if it help you..can you rate it? ..thnx!!..happy to helped you

Comment: When i try to upvote it, it is not casting. saying that votes cast by those who with less than 15 reputations.

Comment: retry ... now ... thnx :)

Comment: I have only 6/15 reputations. so i unable to give you a upvote. I am so sorry for that.:(   But you done a great job. Once again thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Install package `npm-check`, it can be found here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check

Then, in your project console type `npm-check -u`. It will show you interactive menu and you'll be able to check which packages you want to update.